# Почему не выводятся сообщения?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, socket.io

index.js:

```
    var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile('путь до index.html');
});
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
  var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val('');
    return false;
  });
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
  });
</script>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off"><button>Send</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Установлены библиотеки express и socket.io. Вроде бы все работает хорошо, но когда нужно вывести сообщения они не выводятся. В чем проблема?